# Count all rows from all tables in two databases on different servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, ssms-2016

I would like my query to return the table name, and rowcount for all of the tables on our two reporting servers. They both have the same tables. Also, I already added the linked server the other day between these two.

Query so far for one server, not sure how to add a third column connected with our other server though:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.[Rows]
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
    i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND   
    i.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY 
    t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name, p.[Rows]
ORDER BY 
    object_name(i.object_id)
```

**Desired output:**

```
TableName   DB1_rows     DB2_Rows
----------+-----------+-----------
Account   |  20,000   |  19,388
Contacts  |   1,234   |   1,390
Bla       |   2,330   |   2,430
```

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to create a temp table and populate it with your query for each database but add the database/server name. Then you can simply do a self join on table name and do some conditional aggregation to cross tab the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a great use for Common Table Expressions (CTE's) as you can run multiple queries, then join those query results together and analyze/manipulate them in different ways:

```
/* Use the WITH keyword to start your first expression */
WITH SERVER_A AS (
  SELECT 
      t.NAME AS TableName,
      p.[Rows] AS NumRows
  FROM 
      sys.tables t
  INNER JOIN      
      sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
  INNER JOIN 
      sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
  INNER JOIN 
      sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
  WHERE 
      t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
      i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND   
      i.index_id <= 1
  GROUP BY 
      t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name, p.[Rows]
),

/* Then chain additional expressions (this time adding the linked server into the table name) */
SERVER_B AS (
  SELECT 
      t.NAME AS TableName,
      p.[Rows] AS NumRows
  FROM 
      LINKED_SERVER_NAME.sys.tables t
  INNER JOIN      
      LINKED_SERVER_NAME.sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
  INNER JOIN 
      LINKED_SERVER_NAME.sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
  INNER JOIN 
      LINKED_SERVER_NAME.sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
  WHERE 
      t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
      i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND   
      i.index_id <= 1
  GROUP BY 
      t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name, p.[Rows]
)

/* Then join the two together on a common column */
SELECT
  A.TableName,
  A.NumRows AS DB1_Rows,
  B.NumRows AS DB2_Rows

FROM SERVER_A A
  LEFT JOIN SERVER_B B ON
    A.TableName = B.TableName

ORDER BY
  A.TableName ASC
```

You could also accomplish this with `APPLY` statements or correlated sub-queries, but the advantage to using a CTE is that you're not running the sub-query for every single row that the parent query returns. Using a CTE you can run a query and then simply treat that query result as if it were a another table.

Obviously you'll want to test this. I don't have access to a SQL Server at the moment, so there may be a typo here or there.

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for but I'm getting the same row counts for both servers where I know they are different. I tried using the full 4 part name for both queries but still got the same result.

Comment: @JonathanPorter You can highlight the inner part of each CTE and run that query and see the results to make sure they're returning the correct data. If you're using MS SSDT or a similar app you should be able to isolate each query, confirm the datasets and then run the entire query again to confirm you're getting the right output.

Comment: In ssms, when I ran each query independently they returned the same results, but when I changed the server connection the results changed even though I'm using `Server.Database.sys.tables` as an example for the naming. So am I using the convention wrong or does it work differently since they are part of the sys schema?

Comment: [LinkedServer].master.sys.tables should work - as long as your linked server is setup to allow system tables.

On the linked server, you'll need to run:

`GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO <linked-server-username>;`
`GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO <linked-server-username>;`

Grant Database Permissions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569(v=sql.105).aspx

Grant Server Permissions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @RESULT TABLE (TableName VARCHAR(MAX),   DB1_rows  INT,   DB2_Rows INT)
DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR(MAX), @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name FROM sys.tables

OPEN cCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM cCursor INTO @TABLENAME 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT  ''' + @TABLENAME + ''' , COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TABLENAME

        DECLARE @FirstColumn VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 c.name FROM sys.columns c JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id WHERE t.name = @TABLENAME ORDER BY column_id)

        SET @SQL = 'SELECT  ''' + @TABLENAME + ''' , SUM(CASE WHEN A.' + @FirstColumn + ' IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), SUM(CASE WHEN B.' + @FirstColumn + ' IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '
                   +'FROM LIVE.dbo.' + @TABLENAME + ' AS A FULL JOIN TEST.dbo.' + @TABLENAME + ' AS B on 1=0'

        INSERT INTO @RESULT EXEC (@SQL) 

        FETCH NEXT FROM cCursor INTO @TABLENAME 
    END

CLOSE cCURSOR 
DEALLOCATE cCURSOR

SELECT * FROM @RESULT
```

Just change the LIVE and TEST and the 'dbo' schema name on the second line of the 'SET @SQL' statement to the names of the 2 databases.

EDIT: Also you can add one of the database names.schema names to the 'SELECT name FROM sys.tables' statement at the top, plus any table name filtering you wanted to do.

Comment: UGH. Cursors are just the wrong tool for this. They are horribly inefficient. This can be easily solved with a set based query.

Comment: Well the results are exactly what Jonathan wanted. It can be done other ways and if you have a solution feel free to post it

Comment: I tried replacing the LIVE and TEST with the naming convention: Server.DatabaseName and it returned `does not contain the table ""DatabaseName"."dbo"."spt_fallback_db""`

Comment: Did you change the SELECT name FROM system.tables as well to one of the databases?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the result from one server, then you can get the same from other server if the linked server is setup.

You can do it by using the 4 part name. For example:

```
Select ...
From ServerName.DBName.schema.TableName
...
```